# Haskell: find out if an element in a Data.Set starts with a string?

Tags: haskell, set

Since it is possible to check for whether a string is in a set in the following manner:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
S.member "examplestr"
```

I was wondering whether there is a function that tests whether a string is a prefix of a member of the set. For instance, if I want to find out if any of the members of the set begin with the string "ro", the function would return True if there was a string "roller" in the set. 
Thanks for replies

Comment: [`isPrefixOf`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Data-List.html#g:12) ? That said, in your case, that would only work with a single `String`, which is just an alias for `[Char]`

Comment: You can use the function `any` from `Data.Foldable`.

Answer (score 6):

Yep, since `type String = [Char]`, we can use `isPrefixOf`,

```
anyStartsWith :: Eq a => [a] -> Set [a] -> Bool
anyStartsWith str set =  not . S.empty $ S.filter (isPrefixOf str) set
```

Or, since `Set` is foldable,

```
 import qualified Data.Foldable as F
 anyStartsWith str = F.any (isPrefixOf str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a faster O(log(N)) solution:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
import Data.List

s = S.fromList [ "fowl", "foo", "foobar", "goo" ]

hasPrefix key s = case S.lookupGE key s of
        Nothing -> False
        Just p -> key `isPrefixOf` p
```

Here is a shorter variant using `maybe` from `Data.Maybe`:

```
hasPrefix key = maybe False (isPrefixOf key) . S.lookupGE key
```